# Generating permutations of X and Y in Prolog

Tags: prolog, permutation

Basically I have a predicate pair(Z,X,Y)

I want to output all pairs of X and Y from 0 to Z

For example I want a call to look like

```
pair(3,X,Y).
X=0
Y=0;

X=0
Y=1;

X=0
Y=2;

X=0
Y=3;

X=1
Y=0;

X=1
Y=1;
...
X=3
Y=3;
```

So far I have

```
pair(_,0,0).

pair(Z,X,Y) :-
  ...
  pair(S,X2,Y2)
  ...
```

I am new to Prolog so I am unsure how to fill in the areas separated by ...
What I think I should do is say something along the lines of
(In psuedocode)
"If Y2 = S then say X is X1 + 1 and Y is 0"

Or something along those likes.
But this seems like a very roundabout way of doing things. So I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way is to use the built-in predicate `between/3`:

```
pair(S, X, Y):-between(0, S, X), between(0, S, Y).
```

**Edit:**

If you want to *build* the pairs in sequence as you said, you may try something along this line:

```
pair(_, 0, 0).
pair(S, X, Y):- pair(S, X1, Y1),
                (
                 S =:= Y1, (S =:= X1, !, false ; X is X1 + 1, Y is 0)
                ;
                 S =\= Y1, X is X1, Y is Y1 + 1
                ).
```

So, given a pair `(X1, Y1)` you infer the next one `(X, Y)` using the rules you described. If `Y1` is equal to `S`, then you either terminate execute if `X1` is equal to `S` too or you produce the pair `(X1+1, 0)`. If `Y1` is not equal to `S`, then you infer `(X1, Y1+1)`.